# how to get output as 26 if value enterd is 26.5 and 27 if value enterd is 26.6

Tags: .net

Math.Floor(value);

here if the entered value is 26.5,it should come as 26.if value is 26.6,then it should come.Any Math Function can we use or any function can we write to get this output??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
Math.Round(value), 
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.ToEven),
Math.Round(value, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

This will give you the following:

```
   Value      Default    ToEven     AwayFromZero
   12         12         12         12
   12.1       12         12         12
   12.2       12         12         12
   12.3       12         12         12
   12.4       12         12         12
   12.5       12         12         13
   12.6       13         13         13
   12.7       13         13         13
   12.8       13         13         13
   12.9       13         13         13
   13.0       13         13         13
```

According to your question, what you need is `Math.Round`

Comment: This is what `Math.Round(value)` does.

Comment: thanks a lot for the earliest reply.. but still this Math.Round is not working.it.its working like Math.Ceil Method.

Comment: thanks @TempClick..now the code is working..i have used MidpointRounding.Toeven.

Comment: Sure.. How can I do this